# Datepicker with both monthview and eventview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I want to apply a datepicker with this style.

[image: Calende with month and event selector]

I tried almost every plugin but i cant find any suitable solution on how to make this.

I want to click the month on the left to display the dates in the date picker on right and also when i choose a event it must show that events date with month on the datepicker.

Anyone has any suggestion on how to make this or any plugin like this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

check this but you have to alter it for your style in css

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly possible to develop with the ui calendar that is a part of jquery. It does not exist as a ready script so you would have to do some coding.

Datepicker:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

api doc:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

methods, get and set date, should be relevant for you, as well as changemonth option

good luck!